# Give exact value of s as a function of n in closed form

Tags: closed-form

[image: Closed form]

here is what I did so far but I cannot go further[image]

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The innermost step is very easy: $\sum_{k=1}^j 1$ just counts the integers from $1$ to $j$.  For the next two steps you may find the following formulas useful:
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{j=1}^n j &= n(n+1)/2\cr
   \sum_{j=1}^n j^2 &= n(n+1)(2n+1)/6\cr}$$